# What does this icon mean in Delphi code editor?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

In Delphi 10.2.3, I've recently started seeing this weird icon; does anyone know what it means? I am talking about the red circle with a minus sign in it.

[image: Screenshot of a line of code: "property Halt: Boolean read FHalt write FHalt". At the end of the line, there is an icon: a red circle with a white minus sign inside it.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This icon is supposed to inform you that the current line calls the [`Halt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Halt) system procedure.

You get similar icons with `Continue`, `Break`, and `Exit`:

[image: Screenshot of editor window with Continue, Break, Exit, and Halt symbols]

In this case, you have a property with the unfortunate name `Halt`, so the editor confuses this with the `Halt` system procedure.

It is a bad idea to use this property name.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting for sure! I didn't realize what any of those meant, and I will be changing that name, for sure. Now I am glad I asked what I thought was a silly question!

Comment: While I agree that it is a bad idea to call a property or method (or function/procedure) "Halt", the IDE should at least not confuse the declaration of a property called "Halt" with a call to the Halt system function. So this is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: @dummzeuch: I agree, of course.  It also misidentifies identifiers like `var start, &exit: Integer;`

Comment: Seems to be a tradeoff between performance and accuracy.